# Running issue Unable to collect necessary methods for class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, android

I know this question has already been posted but no answer was given as this look to be a stupid question, but if it is answered once I guess it'll avoid more questions

Im getting the following error while running my app:

```
E/TypefaceCompatApi26Impl: Unable to collect necessary methods for class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.graphics.FontFamily.<init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
```

Could someone explain me the meaning of this error ? Im quite new to android programming. There are approx. 30 lines like this, but I would like to understand the issue. The app is launching correctly on AVD and everything's working.

Comment: Adding ` implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.0' ` solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurred **when a particular method cannot be found**.

Please refer to [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodException.html) for more detail and clearance.